# sed -e 's/^M/d' not working

Tags: linux, unix, sed

A very common problem, but I am unable to work around it with sed.

I have a script file ( a batch of commands) say `myfile.txt` to be executed at once to create a list. Now when I am executing a batch operation my command line interface clearly shows its unable to parse the command as a line feed `^M` is adding up at end of each line.

I thought `sed` to be the best way to go about it.I tried:

```
    sed -e 's/^M/d' myfile.txt > myfile1.txt
    mv myfile1.txt myfile.txt
```

It didn't work. I also tried this and it didn't work:

```
    sed -e 's/^M//g' myfile.txt > myfile1.txt
    mv myfile1.txt myfile.txt
```

Then I thought may be `sed` is taking it as a M character in the beginning of line, and hence no result. So I tried:

```
    sed -e 's/\^M//g' myfile.txt > myfile1.txt
    mv myfile1.txt myfile.txt
```

But no change. Is there a basic mistake I am doing ? Kindly advise as I am bad at `sed`.

I found a resolution though which was to open the file in vi editor and in command mode execute this:

```
    :set fileformat=unix
    :w
```

But I want it in `sed` as well.

Comment: This is not what you asked directly: dos2unix, besides sed, also does this.  Your question implied to me that you did not know about it. UNIX has lots of tools, this one is very much a single purpose tool.

Answer (score 12):

`^M` is not literally `^M`. Replace `^M` with `\r`. You can use the same representation for `tr`; these two commands both remove carriage returns:

```
tr -d '\r'  < input.txt > output.txt
sed -e 's/\r//g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/^M/d' myfile.txt
```

Has the following meaning [the same for /\^M/ ]: *If the first letter of the line is M, then remove the line, else print it and pass to next.*. And you have to insert 2 separators /old/new/ in s[earch command].

[This](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Late, but here for posterity: [sed Delete / Remove ^M Carriage Return (Line Feed / CRLF) on Linux or Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-remove-m-and-line-feeds-under-unix-linux-bsd-appleosx/)

The gist, which answers the above question: to get ^M type CTRL+V followed by CTRL+M i.e. don’t just type the carat symbol and a capital M. It will not work